Can third order derivative (jerk) be use for optimization?
In optimization, ussually people just use second order derivative (or Hessian matrix) to classified local extrema. Suppose that my function is 3 times differentiable, what can I use this information for ?
As a follow up I really want to ask about the analog of the jerk (third order derivative) in case of multivariable optimization. Is it some sort of higher dimension matrix ?
All of my questions are just coming from pure curiosity.
Please help me with this
Thank you for your enthusiasm !

Check multi-derivative test. It generalises the second derivative test to higher order.

Can you Recomend some book for me to read please :(

I guess baby Rudin covered it. It just said that if $f^{(1)}(x_0)=f^{(2)}(x_0)=\cdots=f^{(n-1)}(x_0)=0$ but $f^{(n)}(x_0)\ne0$, then it provides some classification results.

Schnabel and his students investigated so-called tensor methods for Optimization and Nonlinear Equations which utilize these higher-order derivatives, or more specifically low-memory approximations to such derivatives.

Here is a comment, too long to write above, that should give you a hand-wavy intuition as to what's going on.
Higher order derivatives are higher degree linear functions (i.e., multilinear). For example, the second derivative of a function really is a bilinear function: if $f$ is differentiable, then we can write $f(x+h)=f(x)+f'(x) \cdot h + e_1(h;x),$ if we can expand $f'(x)$ again, then we can write
$f'(x+k) =f'(x)+f''(x)\cdot k + e_2(k;x),$ so then
\begin{align*}
f(x+k+h)&=f(x+k)+f'(x+k)\cdot h + e_1(h;x+k) \\
&=f(x)+f'(x) \cdot k + e_1(k;x) \\&+f'(x) \cdot h + (f''(x)\cdot k) \cdot h + e_2(k;x) \cdot h\\
&=f(x)+f'(x)\cdot(h+k)+(f''(x)\cdot k) \cdot h+e(h,k;x)
\end{align*}
and it can be easily verified that $(h,k) \mapsto (f''(x) \cdot k)\cdot h$ is linear in $h$ and in $k.$ In a likewise manner, higher order derivatives give rise to multilinear maps.
In regards to how to represent them, we need to remember that linear functions can always be represented by a matrix (having chosen bases), therefore $f'(x)\cdot h = J_f(x) h,$ where $J_f(x)$ is the Jacobian matrix. A bilinear form (i.e., with values in $\mathbf{R}$) can also be represented by a matrix, assuming $f$ is real-valued it can be proven that $(f''(x) \cdot k) \cdot h = h^\intercal H_f(x) k,$ where $H_f(x)$ is the Hessian matrix. Higher order derivatives are not readily representable by matrices, they can be represented by higher dimensional arrays if one is careful with indices but the notation becomes cumbersome.
To answer the question in the title, the answer is yes! First, we have Taylor's theorem in higher dimensions that states
$$
f(x+h) = f(x) + f'(x) + \frac{1}{2} f''(x) + \int\limits_0^1 \frac{(1-t)^2 f'''(x+th) \cdot (h,h,h)}{2} dt.
$$
Suppose now that $f'(x) = 0$ and $f''(x) = 0$ (the linear and bilinear forms equal to zero). Then $f(x+h)-f(x)$ is given by the integral above. If $f'''$ is continuous (the typical case), then the sign of $f'''(x+th) \cdot (h,h,h)$ and of $f'''(x) \cdot(h,h,h)$ will be the same and this sign will be either positive or negative for $h$ and the opposite sign for $-h,$ and since the integral is linear, this will imply at once that $f(x+h)-f(x)$ changes sign in a neighbourhood of $x,$ meaning $x$ is a saddle point. In fact, it can be proven that if $f$ is of class $C^{p+1}$ and the first $p$ derivatives are zero, the $(p+1)$th derivative is not zero at $x,$ then $f$ has a saddle point at $x$ if $p+1$ is odd, and of $p+1$ is even, then $f$ will have a minimum or maximum depending the definitness of the $(p+1)$th derivative. If the $(p+1)$th derivative is not defined ($p+1$ still even and we assume $f^{(p+1)}(x) \cdot h^{(p+1)}$ is $>0$ for some $h$s and $<0$ for some $h$s), then the $x$ is a saddle point again. This result is well-known when $p=1$ (i.e., the second derivative criterion).
I hope these clarify your doubts.
